# CodeName One Animation Questions . . .!

Tags: codenameone

1. Is codenameone support add flash file.
2. Is codenameone support add Gif Image programmatically.
3. how to use create Graphics object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) or any modern mobile doesn't support adding flash files as those aren't designed for the mobile world.

You can add a gif image by using the "Add Animation" option in the designer tool and then using the `getImage(String)` method of the [Resources](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/Resources.html) object. That means you can't download an arbitrary gif off the internet but you can convert it to a res file and download that dynamically.

You can get a graphics object either by overriding [paint(Graphics)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#paint-com.codename1.ui.Graphics-), implementing a painter etc. or by [getGraphics](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#getGraphics--) on a mutable image see more [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html).